# How to verify Android OpenGL ES 2.0 is using GPU

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'd like to verify that the app I'm writing using OpenGL ES 2.0 is in fact using the GPU (and not the CPU for rendering) as per business requirement.

- First I started with a triangle
- Then made that triangle spin
- After that I added a square behind the rotating triangle
- Then I followed the git examples to make the spinning cube

  - I only worked on the cube because `Show GPU view updates` in **android developer options was not flashing for the 2D shapes**
  - **It still didnt flash with the 3D pyramid**
  - From here I enabled `Profile GPU rendering` and ran `adb shell dympsys gfxinfo com.example.openglhelloworld framestats` but didn't seem very different than a non OpenGL sample app I wrote
  - I also set `Enable OpenGL traces` which the top few lines were

```
01-01 08:54:28.022 11026-11026/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
01-01 08:54:28.141 11026-11026/com.example.openglhelloworld W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.openglhelloworld-2/lib/arm
01-01 08:54:28.233 11026-11071/com.example.openglhelloworld D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
01-01 08:54:28.238 11026-11026/com.example.openglhelloworld I/imx6.gralloc: open gpu gralloc module!
01-01 08:54:28.336 11026-11071/com.example.openglhelloworld I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
01-01 08:54:28.358 11026-11071/com.example.openglhelloworld D/libEGL: glGenBuffers(1, (GLuint *) 0xaf61a438);
01-01 08:54:28.358 11026-11071/com.example.openglhelloworld D/libEGL: glBindBuffer(0x8892, 1);
01-01 08:54:28.358 11026-11071/com.example.openglhelloworld D/libEGL: glBufferData(0x8892, 64, (const void *) 0xb5dc8be0, 0x88e4);
01-01 08:54:28.358 11026-11071/com.example.openglhelloworld D/libEGL: glGenBuffers(1, (GLuint *) 0xaf61a45c);
01-01 08:54:28.358 11026-11071/com.example.openglhelloworld D/libEGL: glBindBuffer(0x8893, 2);
```

So my question is, what can I do to verify I'm in fact using the GPU?

Answer (score 0):

If it's a Mali GPU you can use [Streamline in Arm Mobile Studio](https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/graphics-and-gaming/arm-mobile-studio/learn/get-started/get-started-with-streamline) to profile the GPU and see what it's doing.
For GPU profiling generally you'll need tools from the chip designer.